# Memory performance - i7 with 2x4GB 1600MHz or 4x4GB 1333MHz?

Tags: memory, performance

I have Dell Precision m4600 with i7-2820QM CPU.

It supports 1600MHz memory if I use 2 slots, or 1333MHz memory if I use 4 slots.

My question is:

**Which configuration will give me better memory bandwidth?**

**1600MHz 2 slots or 1333MHz 4 slots?**

I don't need more than 8GB RAM, all I care is bandwidth. My CPU has 25.6 GB/s memory bandwidth, but I don't know what memory configuration shall I use to push my CPU/memory controller to the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1600MHz 2 slots, make sure your use matching colored dram slots and that Dual Channel becomes activated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, especially with Chrome the. More RAM is better. If have 32GB and I often see RAM usage above 12GB.